# laravel inner pages are not working on AWS EC2 Nginx

Tags: php, apache, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am working on a `laravel V5.1.11` site which is hosted on `AWS EC2 ubuntu` with `ngnix` server. I successfully setup the site but my inner page are not working.

Config is:

```
server {
  listen 82;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 83;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /home/in4matic/example-website-dev/public;



    location / {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    }


    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        #fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root/index.php;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

    }
}
```

How can I fix that.

Comment: You need to include your nginx configuration. You can add your .htaccess file as well. Migrating a laravel app from a shared hosting is kinda tricky, because you need to remove some "adjustments" that have been made to get laravel up and running on a shared host.

Comment: where I need to include `nginx configuration`

Comment: In your question, to see what might be wrong and provide solution for your problem or some guidance.

Comment: I did nothing till now. just upload the site and set `base_url` in `config/app.php` and some DB setting changes

Answer (score 0):

Moving laravel app from apache to nginx doesn't require many modification, but because laravel uses .htaccess file for url rewrite which won't work in nginx, you have to modify nginx config file so nginx can rewrite url. here is the example of my config file :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  your-website.com;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000 # Keep this as per your old config;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

I have been using this config for all of my laravel app.

and make sure that Storage directory has proper permission.